# DataGrid selectedItem binding with selectedItem in Combox

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex, how can I set the selectedItem of a ComboBox to the selectedItem of a grid (name,mobile,category)? If I select one row in the grid(category), that selected item (category item) must be selected item in categories ComboBox.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="425" height="328" rowCount="5" 
  dataProvider="{contactList}" cornerRadius="3" 
  change="selectedItem=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.groupId;">  
<mx:ComboBox id="grpName" dataProvider="{groupsList}" labelField="groupName"
  selectedIndex="{selectedItem}" />
```

Comment: <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="425" height="328" rowCount="5" dataProvider="{contactList}" 
      cornerRadius="3" change="selectedItem=(event.target as DataGrid).selectedItem.groupId;">

 <mx:ComboBox id="grpName" dataProvider="{groupsList}" labelField="groupName" 
                    
                   selectedIndex="{selectedItem}" />

Comment: thatis just possible not in felx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data provider of the `ComboBox` and the `DataGrid` are similar (of same length and contents) you can bind the `selectedIndex` property to achieve this.

```
<mx:ComboBox selectedIndex="{dg.selectedIndex}"/>
```